# Read online data into Excel - from PHP server?

Tags: php, excel, report

I want to connect Excel to my web site, as an external data source, and thereby run reports on the data that is fetched from my website. I have heard that this should be possible to do and Excel seems to support it, but I have little knowledge on how I actually should build the backend on my PHP server to serve the data. How do I do it?

I am well aware of the fact of being able to create and read Excel files on a PHP server, but that's not what I am after.

Comment: Define "from PHP" - does that mean from a database? If so, which one?

Comment: I use mongoDB and mySQL databases, so if I could use one PHP file to query both databases and write out the desired info which Excel could fetch, it would be super.

Comment: @stillstanding: I have no experience of ODBC - I guess that requires me to setup an additional server for this?

Comment: Just an ODBC driver. If you're using PDO for both MongoDB and mySQL then it should be trivial to add ODBC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel supports IQY, internet queries.
You may define one in excel pointing at your webserver and get the data right into excel.
You may use formatted html-tables at your server. Colors will be preserved.

the iry-format is described at:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/157482
and supports both post/get and parameters.

regards
//t

Comment: Great answer! I have used web queries before, but never would have thought of it.